# Get total for column in sqlite select

Tags: sqlite

Want to select 3 item with values by random and show its total at the end

Example:

```
A  diner 2
B  lunch 3
C  diner 4
D  lunch 5
```

I want result for diner like:

```
A 2
C 4
Total 6
```

Comment: SELECT *,  SUM(tableName.colomnNumberQnt) as Total from tableName WHERE tableName.colomnNameDietAction = "diner";

Comment: please include your database table to your post for better understanding.

Comment: Check out this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329492/3409734), this may help you with **random row selection**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

`STRING QUERY = SELECT SUM(COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY) FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME_TIME_OF_MEAL = "diner"`

After executing this query, it should return the total for `diner`.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky because it involves persisting the random rows to perform aggregation.
So I use a CTE that returns the random rows along with a dummy row containing the string 'Total' and a value of `0` for `Col3`.
Finally with CASE the code returns either `Col3`, if the row is one of the random rows or the sum of all the values in `Col3` if the row is the *Total* row:

```
with cte as ( 
  select * from (
    select 0 sortorder, col1, col3
    from tablename
    where col2 = 'diner'
    order by random()
    limit 2
  )  
  union all
  select 1, 'Total', 0
)
select col1,
  case
    when sortorder = 0 then col3
    else sum(col3) over()
  end Total
from cte
order by sortorder
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kyPQpc2y1j5fTQJRvKaXCW/3) (I added more rows to your sample data).